# Does tf.contrib.eager.list_devices() work on AI Platform machines?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to set up a Tensorflow training job on AI Platform and want to be able to dynamically configure how many GPUs to use. Currently to get the number of GPUs, I am using:

```
distribution_strategy = None
# Get the available GPU devices
num_gpus = len([device_name
                for device_name in tf.contrib.eager.list_devices()
                if '/device:GPU' in device_name])
logging.info('%s GPUs are available.', str(num_gpus))
if num_gpus > 1:
  distribution_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
  logging.info('MirroredStrategy will be used for training.')
  # Update the batch size
  args.batch_size = int(math.ceil(args.batch_size / num_gpus))
```

However, it appears this only works when I run locally. Why does this not work when I run my job on AI Platform with workerType `complex_model_m_gpu`, and what alternatives can I use to achieve the intended effect?

More information: my config file looks like:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: large_model
  workerType: complex_model_m_gpu
  parameterServerType: large_model
  workerCount: 3
  parameterServerCount: 1
```

Comment: Looks like you are not using ParameterServer strategy why to define ParameterServer architecture? and also what do you mean it doesn't work. What do you see?

Comment: MirroredStrategy is normally used for multiple GPUs in same host, have you tried adding GPUs in your "parameterServerType: complex_model_m_v100" as current one doesn't have GPU: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/machine-types#compare-machine-types in legacy ParameterServer strategy Master uses CPU and Workers GPU, depending on your code structure code may be running in Master only.